# Beef Short ribs still chewy after internal temperature reach 201F

Tags: barbecue, ribs

so i currently start to cook beef short ribs on a vertical smoker.

The short ribs i used comes from australian company called hardwicks.

I cook the ribs at 250-285F. Vent are fully opened. Weather is sunny. I marinade them on sweet soy sauce overnight. I use black pepper, cumin powder, paprika powder, onion powder, garlic powder, and sea salt. I spritz them when it reaches 170, and when it hits 190, i wrap it on alumunium foil with some spritz. After hitting 201F i take it out, rest it for an hour, but instead of being butter-like texture, it still chewy.

I don't know how long i cook, i jjst focused on the internal temperature itself.

So does anyone know why it still chewy and not butter-like when it cutted?
Thanks everyone, sorry bcs english is not my first language. Cheers!

Comment: I'd think chewy or not would be a factor of whether the collagen and connective tissues have had enough time to break down.  So, it's not just important about the temperatures used, but how long.  How long, at those temps, does it take to get to that internal temperature?  The mantra is "low and ***slow***," so we need more info on duration.